# How to add multiple canvases to a picturebox?

Tags: c#, canvas, element, preview, drawrectangle

Let me explain my problem:

I have a picturebox and this should be used to draw several elements of a listbox.
I gave the picturebox a canvas. by left and rightclick u can put up a rectangle which should preview the element u want to draw on the canvas of the picturebox.

Now this is my problem:

this rectangle should just be a preview and should be erased every time i click on a another position of the picturebox and put up a new rectangle. it should just be drawn on the canvas when i click on the inputbutton.

So how can i preview the chosen elements in the rectangle made by left and rightclick?

I hope my question is clealy enough : /

This is what i did so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Interaktive_systeme_sta
{
    public partial class Bildeditor : Form
    {


        void drawRect()
        {
            pbxBild.Refresh();

            using (Graphics g = this.pbxBild.CreateGraphics())
            {

                Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
                blackPen.DashPattern = new float[] {2,2};

                int X = Convert.ToInt32(nupX.Value);
                int Y = Convert.ToInt32(nupY.Value);
                int B = Convert.ToInt32(nupBreite.Value);
                int H = Convert.ToInt32(nupHoehe.Value);

                g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, X, Y, B, H);

                g.Dispose();

            }
        }

        public Bildeditor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.MinimumSize = new Size(630,420);
            this.MaximumSize = new Size(630, 420);

            int canvasWidth = pbxBild.Width;
            int canvasHeight = pbxBild.Height;

            nupBreite.Maximum = canvasWidth;
            nupHoehe.Maximum = canvasHeight;

            nupBreite.Minimum = 0;
            nupHoehe.Minimum = 0;

            nupBreite.Value = canvasWidth;
            nupHoehe.Value = canvasHeight;

            nupX.Maximum = canvasWidth;
            nupY.Maximum = canvasHeight;

            nupX.Minimum = 0;
            nupY.Minimum = 0;

            nupX.Value = 0;
            nupY.Value = 0;

            drawRect();

        }

        private void btnZuruecksetzten_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int canvasWidth = pbxBild.Width;
            int canvasHeight = pbxBild.Height;

            nupX.Value = 0;
            nupY.Value = 0;
            nupBreite.Value = canvasWidth-1;
            nupHoehe.Value = canvasHeight-1;
        }

        private void numericUpDown2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            drawRect();
        }

        private void pbxBild_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point mouseDownLocation = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

            switch (e.Button)
            {
                case MouseButtons.Left:
                    if (e.X < 0)
                    {
                        nupX.Value = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nupX.Value = e.X;
                    }
                    if (e.Y < 0)
                    {
                        nupY.Value = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nupY.Value = e.Y;
                    }
                    break;
                case MouseButtons.Right:

                    if (e.X - nupX.Value < 1)
                    {
                        nupBreite.Value = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nupBreite.Value = e.X - nupX.Value;
                    }

                    if (e.Y - nupY.Value < 1)
                    {
                        nupHoehe.Value = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nupHoehe.Value = e.Y - nupY.Value;
                    }
                    break;
            }

            drawRect();
        }

        private void nupY_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            drawRect();
        }

        private void nupBreite_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            drawRect();
        }

        private void nupHoehe_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            drawRect();
        }

        private void btnEinfuegen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lbBildelemente.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                zeichneBild();
            }
            else if (lbBildelemente.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                zeichneLine();
            }
            else if (lbBildelemente.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                zeichneRect();
            }
            else if (lbBildelemente.SelectedIndex == 3)
            {
                zeichneText();
            }
            else if (lbBildelemente.SelectedIndex == 4)
            {
                zeichneKreis();
            }
        }

        private void lbBildelemente_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lbBildelemente.SelectedIndex == 0) 
            {
                tbFarbe.Enabled = false;
                btnFarbe.Enabled = false;
                nupPen.Enabled = false;

                tbBild.Enabled = true;
                btnBild.Enabled = true;

                tbText.Enabled = false;

                tbSchrift.Enabled = false;
                btnSchrift.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (lbBildelemente.SelectedIndex == 1 || lbBildelemente.SelectedIndex == 2 || lbBildelemente.SelectedIndex == 4)
            {
                tbFarbe.Enabled = true;
                btnFarbe.Enabled = true;
                nupPen.Enabled = true;

                tbBild.Enabled = false;
                btnBild.Enabled = false;

                tbText.Enabled = false;

                tbSchrift.Enabled = false;
                btnSchrift.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (lbBildelemente.SelectedIndex == 3)
            {
                tbFarbe.Enabled = true;
                btnFarbe.Enabled = true;
                nupPen.Enabled = true;

                tbBild.Enabled = false;
                btnBild.Enabled = false;

                tbText.Enabled = true;

                tbSchrift.Enabled = true;
                btnSchrift.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        void zeichneBild()
        {
            Graphics g = pbxBild.CreateGraphics();

            int X = Convert.ToInt32(nupX.Value);
            int Y = Convert.ToInt32(nupY.Value);
            int B = Convert.ToInt32(nupBreite.Value);
            int H = Convert.ToInt32(nupHoehe.Value);

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(tbBild.Text);
            g.DrawImage(bitmap, X, Y, B, H);
        }

        // Als zusatzfunktion kann man die Pinseldicke auswählen

        void zeichneRect() 
        {
            Graphics g = pbxBild.CreateGraphics();

            Pen Pen = new Pen(tbFarbe.BackColor, Convert.ToInt32(nupPen.Value));

            int X = Convert.ToInt32(nupX.Value);
            int Y = Convert.ToInt32(nupY.Value);
            int B = Convert.ToInt32(nupBreite.Value);
            int H = Convert.ToInt32(nupHoehe.Value);

            g.DrawRectangle(Pen, X, Y, B, H);
        }

        //zusatzfunktion

        void zeichneKreis()
        {
            Graphics g = pbxBild.CreateGraphics();

            Pen Pen = new Pen(tbFarbe.BackColor, Convert.ToInt32(nupPen.Value));

            int X = Convert.ToInt32(nupX.Value);
            int Y = Convert.ToInt32(nupY.Value);
            int B = Convert.ToInt32(nupBreite.Value);
            int H = Convert.ToInt32(nupHoehe.Value);

            g.DrawEllipse(Pen, X, Y, B, H);
        }

        void zeichneLine()
        {
            Graphics g = pbxBild.CreateGraphics();

            Pen Pen = new Pen(tbFarbe.BackColor, Convert.ToInt32(nupPen.Value));

            int X = Convert.ToInt32(nupX.Value);
            int Y = Convert.ToInt32(nupY.Value);
            int B = Convert.ToInt32(nupBreite.Value);
            int H = Convert.ToInt32(nupHoehe.Value);

            g.DrawLine(Pen, X, Y, X+B, Y+H);
        }

        void zeichneText()
        {
            Graphics g = pbxBild.CreateGraphics();

            Brush brush = new SolidBrush(tbFarbe.BackColor);

            int X = Convert.ToInt32(nupX.Value);
            int Y = Convert.ToInt32(nupY.Value);

            g.DrawString(tbText.Text, fontDialog1.Font, brush, X, Y);
        }

        private void btnFarbe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                tbFarbe.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
            }
        }

        private void btnSchrift_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Show the dialog.
            DialogResult result = fontDialog1.ShowDialog();
            // See if OK was pressed.
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // Get Font.
                Font font = fontDialog1.Font;
                // Set TextBox properties.
                this.tbSchrift.Text = string.Format(font.Name +"; "+ font.Size +"pt");
            }
        }

        private void btnBild_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Joint Photographic Experts Group (*.jpg)|*.jpg|"
                + "EMF Enhanced Metafile Format (*.emf)|*.emf|"
                + "Graphics Interchange Format (*.gif)|*.gif|"
                + "Bitmap (*.bmp)|*.bmp|"
                + "W3C Portable Network Graphics (*.png)|*.png";

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                tbBild.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void bildbereichLöschenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pbxBild.Refresh();
        }

        private void bildLadenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Joint Photographic Experts Group (*.jpg)|*.jpg|"
                + "EMF Enhanced Metafile Format (*.emf)|*.emf|"
                + "Graphics Interchange Format (*.gif)|*.gif|"
                + "Bitmap (*.bmp)|*.bmp|"
                + "W3C Portable Network Graphics (*.png)|*.png";

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Graphics g = pbxBild.CreateGraphics();

                int X = 0;
                int Y = 0;
                int B = Convert.ToInt32(pbxBild.Width);
                int H = Convert.ToInt32(pbxBild.Height);

                Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(openFileDialog.FileName);
                g.DrawImage(bitmap, X, Y, B, H);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you did so far?

Comment: What do you mean? You want that when you click on a certain image it gets displayed in the pictureBox?

Comment: ya its like u chose a element from a listbox with 4 elements. for example a line, circle, text or a picture.jpg. by clicken left and right with ur mouse u can set up a rectangle wich is ur space to put the chosen element on the canvas. my prob is that this should just be a preview und not be allready drawn on the canvas when its being displayed on the picturebox. it should be drawn by clicking on "input element". so when i chose a element from the listbox, it should be shown in the rectangle everywhere i set it up, but not be drawn, just previewed.

Comment: we got a example.exe from our teacher. iam gonna set up a picture and try to explain it more with it, so u can see exactly what i mean. will take a bit, ty so far : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
}
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedItem == "Circle")
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = circle;
    }
}
```